# Requested transaction isolation level is not honored by the SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

We have some instances where multiple applications depend on the completed work of the others. We start and commit our transactions via the Database property of our Entity Framework `DatabaseContext`.

Like this:

```
public void StartTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable)
{           
    CheckTransactionNotActive();

    if (!Database.Connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
    {
        Database.Connection.Open();
    }

    _transaction = Database.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
}
```

This results in the following when watching the created transaction in the debugger:

[image: Code transaction]

However SQL Server Profiler shows another picture:

[image: Db transaction]

How is this possible, and how do we prevent it!?

**Update**

rewrote my test to use TransactionScope:
The following code is executed from multiple tasks

```
        var context = new MyDbContext();
        var myRepository = new MyRepository(context);

        using (
            TransactionScope scope =
                new TransactionScope(
                    TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                    new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable })
             )
        {
            var x = my.GetAll().First();
            Console.WriteLine("before " + x.Count);
            x.count = x.count + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("after " + x.Count);
            context.SaveChanges(false);
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

The output shows that my requested transaction isolation level is not honored

[image]

Comment: This might give you some insight into why this is happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273933/setting-transaction-isolation-level-in-net-entity-framework-for-sql-server

Comment: @TTeeple It is somewhat helpful, but I'm not using transaction scope, I'm starting an explicit database transaction.